# Understanding Implicit hash within a ruby method definition

Tags: ruby

I was watching the [CooperPress](https://youtu.be/u8Q6Of_mScI) Youtube video that discusses different ways to specify arguments with defaults within a method definition.

He discusses how in Ruby 2.0 there is some syntactic sugar which allows you to specify an *implicit* hash that also sets default values for each `key` within this hash. Located at [this part](https://youtu.be/u8Q6Of_mScI?t=3m31s) of the video, but I will redisplay the code below:

```
def some_method(x: 10, y: 20, z: 30)
  puts x
  puts y
  puts z
end

some_method x: 1, y: 2

=> 1
=> 2
=> 30
```

What I am having trouble understanding is why turning that *implicit* hash into an *explicit* hash doesn't work.  Basically: all I am doing is putting curly braces around that *implicit* hash argument within the method definition.  As I see it: putting curly braces around the key/values is just a more explicit way to say that a hash wraps those key/values and it should have the exact same behavior. However, when I do this it errors out:

```
def some_method({x: 10, y: 20, z: 30}) #curly braces here
  puts x
  puts y
  puts z
end

some_method x: 1, y: 2

=> rb:1: syntax error, unexpected {, expecting ')' def some_method({x: 10, y: 20, z: 30})
```

**Question:** Why does turning that *implicit* hash argument within the method definition into an *explicit* hash argument make the method error out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't watched that video, but "implicit hash" is a poor choice of words. This is a feature called "keyword arguments" and it has a pretty specific syntax which, yes, resembles a hash, but isn't one.

For example, it allows required arguments, which is impossible in a hash.

```
def foo(required:, optional: 1)
  # some code
end
```

Comment: I just watched the video because I was quite surprised that Peter Cooper would use such shoddy sloppy terminology. Well, as it turns out, there is actually no mention of an *implicit hash* anywhere in the video at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are special syntax rules for what you can write in a method argument definition, you cannot just write arbitrary expressions.

You could write this:

```
def foo(opts = arbitrary_hash)
```

That would mean the method has one argument and its default value is whatever `arbitrary_hash` is, but that would be an unusual way to do it because then if you pass any argument to the method, none of the defaults get applied.